# Positioning forms in html

Tags: php, html, css

Hi there I have two forms that display results based on user inputed data (php/database query) into tabular format. My problem is that both of the forms are positioned on the left hand side of the page and when i run the second form it places the table in the position where the the first query should be. I would like the second form to be placed to the right hand side of the page so that the first form table displays on the left hand side of the page and the second form table displays on the right hand side of the page. I have used methods like "align=right" but this hasnt worked. Any idea on how i can achieve this. Here is my code.

```
 $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<td><strong><font color="#000000">ID</font></strong></td>';
            $table .= '<td><strong><font color="#000000">Name</font></strong></td>';
            $table .= '<td><strong><font color="#000000">Contact</font></strong></td>';
            $table .= '<td><strong><font color="#000000">Start Date</font></strong></td>';
            $table .= '<td><strong><font color="#000000">End Date</font></strong></td>';
            $table .= '<td><strong><font color="#000000">Facility ID</font></strong></td>';
            $table .= '</tr>';


            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['id'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['name'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['contact'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['start'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['end'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['resource_id'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '</tr>';
            }
            $table .= '</table>';
            echo $table;
        }
    }
?>
    <form method="POST">
        Start DATE: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
        End DATE: <input type="text" name="end" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />

    </form>
     <form method="POST">
            <h3  style="font-family:verdana;"> <u>Search a name</u></h3>
             Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what you need is css... try using [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) or [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).
Also you have to Echo the result of the php code below the forms. 
if you use Skeleton you might have something like this:

```css
/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
  font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222; }


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }


/* Links
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
a {
  color: #1EAEDB; }
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE; }


/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
hr {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }


/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }


/* Media Queries
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/*
Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries
near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons
on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it
there.
*/


/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="six columns" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns" >
            <h4>Form 1</h4>
            <hr/>
            <form method="POST">
                Start DATE: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
                End DATE: <input type="text" name="end" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="six columns" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns" >
            <h4>Form 2</h4>
            <hr/>
            <form method="POST">
                    <h3  style="font-family:verdana;"> <u>Search a name</u></h3>
                     Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns" >
            <h4>My result</h4>
            <hr/>
            <!-- Php Code here -->
            Php Code here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the two forms in a div

```
<div class="forms">
<form></form>
<form></form>
</div>
```

Use the flex property

```
.forms{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

For more information on flexbox, visit https://flexbox.io/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox